# What is XML Vocabulary? need some clarity on it

Tags: xml

I have a doubt in XML Vocabulary.

XML schema is an alternative to the DTD's.
XSLT is an stylesheet for XML

I am clear on the XML schema and XSLT.

But what is XML Vocabulary?
It is also simillar to an XML schema or DTD or it is a collection of well defined XML schema?

Sorry for asking this silly question i was googling for more than an hour to find what is a XML vocabulary but i haven got a clarity on the XML vocabulary.

I got something like this while browsing

> Book XML vocabulary - just for marking up book data:

```
<Book>
    <Title>The Wisdom of Crowds</Title>
    <Classification>non-fiction</Classification>
    <Author>James Surowiecki</Author>
</Book>
```

Music XML vocabulary - just for marking up music data:

```
<Musical-Score>
   <Work>Winterreise</Work>
   <Genre>classical</Genre>
   <Composer>Franz Schubert</Composer>
</Musical-Song>
```

Here the same data is marked up, this time using a single generic XML
vocabulary:

Composition XML vocabulary - for marking up any literary data:

```
<Composition class="Book">
    <Title>The Wisdom of Crowds</Title>
    <Category>non-fiction</Category>
    <Creator>James Surowiecki</Creator>
</Composition>

<Composition class="Musical-Score">
    <Title>Winterreise</Title>
    <Category>classical</Category>
    <Creator>Franz Schubert</Creator>
</Composition>
```

After seeing this i am still confused why and how it is usefull?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For e.g let us say you want to represent person information. In HTML you have to use pre-defined vocabulary (as it doesn't allow you to create your own) so you can represent a person as below

```
<h1>Bob Joe</h1>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Weight</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>140</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

XML lets you **create your own vocabulary or tags** that is meaningful as shown in below example. You can even restrict the vocabulary (**so that exchange and processing of information is simplified**) using XSD or DTD.

```
<Person>
  <Name>Bob Joe</Name>
  <Age>30</Age>
  <Weight>140<Weight>
</Person>
```

Once you have created the vocabulary using XSD then you can associate it with an XML instance using **xsi namespacce** as shown below

```
<Person
  xmlns="MyDefaultNamespace"
  xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
  xsi:schemaLocation="MyDefaultNamespace Person.xsd">

  <Name>Bob Joe</Name>
  <Age>30</Age>
  <Weight>140<Weight>
</Person>
```

A program can validate the XML instance against a XSD programatically using the api provided in a particular language. Many languages have this support. There are also tools that can generate code to parse and create xml adhering to a XSD.

Comment: I have got the idea the using an XML vocabulary we can define our own tags, But how to use it?

For eg XSLT ,means in the xml i have to add one tag to link the stylesheet with the xml. Same way if i define a vocabulary how a vocabulary should be and how it can be accessed and checked. 

Is there any web page with sample demonstration how it is used in the application?

Whether we are referring the vocabulary in the XML via namespaces?

Comment: is "MyDefaultNamespace" the prefix I would like to use? For example if I wanted my prefix to be "xs" would I have `xmlns="xs"` ?

Answer (score 3):

The term "XML vocabulary" does not have a precise meaning in the way that XSD or DTD does. The term is used by people to mean "a collection of element and attribute names with definitions of their meanings and their structural relationships and constraints". A schema or DTD might be part of that, but the emphasis is on what the elements mean, which is likely to involve documentation in English or other natural languages. So for example the "MusicXML schema" allows you to distinguish valid instances from invalid instances, but the "MusicXML vocabulary" tells you that a particular element/attribute represents a musical note with a given pitch, duration, and loudness.

Answer (score 1):

XML is basis for creating different XML based documents, e.g.: XSLT, SOAP, RSS, SVG, etc. These documents are XML documents, but at the same time they have own XML vocabulary defined using XSD, DTD or any other mechanism of XML vocabulary description.

Comment: Is there any webPage dedicated to XML vocabulary where i can get more information?

Answer (score 0):

These are standards on top of basic xml.
For e.g ->SOAP,UDDI and WSDL